# Azure database migration

Tags: azure-sql-database

Does anyone know what SQL runs during the Azure Data Migration Assistant process when deploying data?

I see a pause at the beginning, then the data is copied, then a pause at the end.

My suspicion is the beginning is disabling foreign keys and indexes and the end is re-enabling those, but I can't find an explanation anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Data Migration Assistant (DMA) uses the bulk copy APIs to read the data in parallel among the tables and databases and perform bulk inserts into the target tables.  We disable the FKs, non-clustered indexes ahead of the migration and re-enable after the migration is done.
During the above activity you may see pause in migration activity.
Thanks
Raj Pochiraju